# MS SQL Connection to Python

Tags: python, django, pyodbc, django-pyodbc

I'm getting an error that Django did not find the `pyodbc` library in the build directory.  Will use an installed version.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ggang1\Downloads\pyodbc-4.0.17\pyodbc-4.0.17\tests3\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pyodbc
ImportError: No module named pyodbc
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Django are you using? Are you using a `virtualenv`? I'd strongly recommend using a `virtualenv`, and if you're connecting to SQL Server, I normally use the `django-pyodbc-azure` library: https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure It works for SQL Server on or off Azure, and works with the latest version of Django.